# Does calling Select() or GroupBy() in Linq to entities trigger querying the database?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a hard time telling what operations in linq cause a SQL command to be issued to the database.

I know calling ToList() or iterating w/ foreach will cause the query to run but do Select and GroupBy cause the code to execute on the database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they don't, if they're correctly called on the `IQueryable` rather than the `IEnumerable`, they are compiled as expressions and will later be translated to SQL.

You can use the intellisense tooltip to see which will be the currently called method. If the first parameter of the extension method is `IEnumerable` rather than `IQueryable`, you'll run into a database query.

Comment: Are you sure calling GroupBy on an IEnumerable rather than an IQueryable will cause the query to be sent to the database? I thought it was only when you begin enumerating that the query is sent.

Answer (score 3):

No, `Select`, `GroupBy` and most other methods will not cause a database request. A database request will typically only be made when you do something that requires the results to be known, such as calling `Count` or `ToList` as you mentioned.

To help you see when database queries are made it might help to log them. Then as you step through the code you can see when the query is sent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't think I can see a running Log in Linq-to-entities...

Comment: You could perhaps look at this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137712/sql-tracing-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 1):

No, calling Select() and GroupBy() will not hit the database. Only when the actual result is required (when enumerating, using ToList(), ToArray(), Count() etc) will the query get executed against the database.

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, very late answer.
As already answered, NO it won't trigger. However, sounds like there are not much methods triggering db calls in iqueryables per the answers above.. There are actually a lot that will ruin your IQueryable in certain scenarios.. It is a very common mistake in huge IQueryables which I wanted to point out.

Below are the list in an asc order which will ruin your query most of the time (especially if you are selecting some of the column values with one of those below):

- Aggregate
- All
- Any
- Average
- Contains
- Count
- ElementAt
- ElementAtOrDefault
- Empty
- First
- FirstOrDefault
- Last
- LastOrDefault
- LongCount
- Max
- Min
- SequenceEqual
- Single
- SingleOrDefault
- Sum
- ToArray
- ToDictionary
- ToList
- ToLookup

You check the whole [Classification Table here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution). That shows all the Immediate Executions, Deferred Streaming Execution as well as the Deferred Non Streaming Execution.